# Как создать файл css в intellij idea community edition?

Tags: css, javafx

Как создать файл css в intellij idea community edition?его просто нету во вкладке добавить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Третий сверху пункт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File -> Create new File -> File -> style.css.

В Community версии нет поддержки CSS, как обычного так м javafx версию, возможность работы как с файлом никуда не пропала, просто не будет автокомплита.